# regarding the usage of runif function

Tags: r

I once saw the following R code,

```
x<-runif(3,max=c(10,20,30))
```

If the `min` is not set, what's the lower range for the generated random variable. Besides,when `max` is setup this way, my understanding is that it will iterate over the three values given in `c()` for each generated variable, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `?runif` help page, you'll see the default for `min=` is 0.

If you specify multiple values for max, the values are recycled so it's like the first value comes from unif(0,10), the second from unif(0,20) and the third from (0,30) and that pattern repeats for as many values as you request. If you only request one value

```
runif(1, max=c(10,20,30)
```

that would be the same as

```
runfi(1, max=10)
```

This is noted in the help page under the Value section

> The numerical arguments other than `n` are recycled to the length of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation for this function (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Uniform), `min` takes on the value 0 unless explicitly passed.

And yes, that is correct - the function will iterate over the values given in c() for each value.  If there isn't a value passed (e.g. you're generating 3 random variables and set c=(1,2)), then max will take the default value of 1 for the elements that don't have a set max value.  An example showing how it iterates over c():

```
x<-runif(3,max=c(1,20, 7000000))
 x
[1]      0.622216      7.463306 809194.417205
```